# Servicebus and Function App(Vnet) integration

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-virtual-network, azure-function-app

I am using Topic trigger for function app. I have my function app inside the Vnet but not the service bus. I can see the messages are not getting triggered/received by the function. Does that mean that both service bus and Function app should be inside the Vnet or is there any other option I could Try.

If I move out of the Vnet in Function App, everything seems fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: please explain what kind of VNET integration you have configured. Regional VNET or another one? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

Comment: its regional, for test I have created premium tier service bus and put that inside the vnet. messages seems to be reaching the function app.

Comment: did you turn on force tunneling on your function (WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL=1)?

Comment: its set to 1 right now

Comment: then try to disable it (remove the setting). It could be that your VNET has some firewall or routing issues so that your AppService cannot reach your Service Bus through it

Comment: you are right. I am able to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, VNet Integration gives your app access to resources in your VNet, but it doesn't grant inbound private access to your app from the VNet. This will not impact your outbound traffic to your Azure service bus. You don't need to set `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL=1`.

[image]

Verify that there is neither service endpoint enabled nor NSG rules blocking on the integrated subnet.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using Regional VNet Integration, there are couple of things that needs to be in place to ensure the function app can connect with Key vault

- Keyvault service endpoint needs to be enabled on the integration subnet.
- the integration subnet needs to be whitelisted on the Keyvault firewall. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/network-security).

There is however a scenario that currently doesn't work because of architectural limitations. See this: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/38817385-allow-key-vault-references-to-access-secrets-behin

If the KeyVault endpoint is being passed through app settings, then this scenario currently doesn't work. If your function code, access the key vault endpoint direcly, then that should probably work.